# SSRS - Replace the Chart

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bar-chart, ssrs-grouping

I have a question, want some assistance.

Q) My question is that i have a chart in which analyst assigned for many incidents and some analyst have 1 or two incident assigned. just because of this the bar chart looks ugly some time. So thats why i used a new chart to represent Min incident count. But i want there some creativeness, for which i want there a radio button or OnClick event ( I do not know how to use both these. When report runs by default it`ll show Max incidents count chart and when we used radio button it will show Min incidents count chart, on the same chart area no need of new area or on new page.

Kindly help me or refer me some links and with ideas. As i have searched many blogs but i didn`t get any big achievement.

Below is my Simplified query;

```
SELECT
Count(IncidentDimvw.Id)
,UserDimvw.FirstName AS Analyst
FROM
IncidentDimvw
FULL JOIN WorkItemDimvw
ON IncidentDimvw.EntityDimKey = WorkItemDimvw.EntityDimKey
JOIN WorkItemAssignedToUserFactvw
ON WorkItemDimvw.WorkItemDimKey = WorkItemAssignedToUserFactvw.WorkItemDimKey
JOIN UserDimvw
ON WorkItemAssignedToUserFactvw.WorkItemAssignedToUser_UserDimKey = UserDimvw.UserDimKey
    WHERE
  WorkItemAssignedToUserFactvw.DeletedDate IS NULL
    GROUP BY
UserDimvw.FirstName
Having (Count(IncidentDimvw.Id) = (@Count))
```

Having Clause is right or wrong, i donot know.
I used the following expresion in series as you suggested.

```
=iif(Parameters!Count.Value, Max(Sum(Fields!ID.Value)), Min(Sum(Fields!ID.Value)))
```

Sample data is as folows;

[image: Achiving result]

Regards

Muhammad Ahsan

Comment: There are at least three distinct issues here - a custom order for the Status field, Custom palette colours not working as required, and controlling chart behaviour through parameters. I think all of these are probably answerable, but it's easiest to manage when a posted question describes only one issue. That way an answer can address only the issue at hand. I would recommend splitting the issues in the question above into multiple questions describing one issue each to better fit the SO format.

Comment: thanks for the responce Preston
As you suggested i had edit my question and just asked right here what should be most importantly want to know.

Comment: Great, thanks, I've done my best to answer the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of ways to approach this:

**Dynamic expressions based on parameter**

Say you have a simple DataSet like:

[image]

And also a boolean parameter called **showMax**.

We can create a simple bar graph based on this:

[image]

The most important thing to note is that Series value is expression-based:

[image]

In the above example the expression is:

```
=IIf(Parameters!showMax.Value
  , Max(Fields!value.Value)
  , Min(Fields!value.Value))
```

i.e. when **showMax** is *true*, report the Max values, otherwise report the min values.

In this case I've also updated the **Axis title**, **Chart title**, and **Custom legend text** to be expression-based:

Axis Title: `=IIf(Parameters!showMax.Value, "Max", "Min")`

Chart Title: `=IIf(Parameters!showMax.Value, "Max per group", "Min per group")`

Custom legend text: `=IIf(Parameters!showMax.Value, "Max value", "Min value")`

The chart behaviour changes based on what parameter is selected as required:

[image]

[image]

**Set Visibility based on parameter**

Another option is simply to have to charts and hide one depending on parameter selection.

For example, for the Max chart the **Hidden** property can be set to:

```
=Not(Parameters!showMax.Value)
```

Setting this property correctly for each report will mean only one is ever displayed to the user, i.e. it will look dynamic.

Either of these options should work; the first keeps the layout simple in the designer makes the chart more complex, the second makes the layout more complex but keeps the charts simple.

Hopefully one option will work for you.

Comment: Hi thanks Preston, is that also posible that i want to define min value <= 5 and Max value > 5. now it represent the bar chart upon this senerio.

Comment: It gives me an output on "True", show exactly 1 incidents against all the analyst and if "False" selected "No data available" is shown. Kindly Help me on this.

Comment: What is your opinion in this regard.
i get this result, if Selecting "True" to all analysts has 1 incidents, on otherside if Selecting "False" after running the report it shows "No Data Available". I want to know if there's any mistake or suddest me any thing.

Comment: Sorry, it's impossible to tell what's happening without seeing your specific data - my answer was mainly to show how you can apply expressions in a chart. As with all these sort of questions it's easiest to try and illustrate with the simplest possible example, i.e. you give a simple dataset of a few rows/columns with your desired results, and explain why you couldn't achieve this. You've added some code above but it's far too complex to understand - the query isn't even important, just the end results.

Comment: way of your answer is perfect. I want the same result as shown in your images. Sorry to say i again edit my question to clearify my need and also added a picture. I am using the following expression in series, but if i select boolean button "true" it shows the 1 incident against all analyst, and if selecting "false" it shows "No Data Available".
'=iif(Parameters!Count.Value, Max(Sum(Fields!ID.Value)), Min(Sum(Fields!ID.Value)))'
'=iif(Parameters!Count.Value, Max(Fields!ID.Value), Min(Fields!ID.Value))

I tried both expression but result set have no effect. Kindly help on this.